# Is it possible to check equality of closures in rust?

Tags: rust, closures, programming-languages

I am pretty new to rust, but for a practice project I am working on, I would like to implement a React useMemo like API, and I thought if the type of the closure is static, and the capture variables are stored somewhere, should I not be able to check equality?

Something like:

```
let cached = scope.use_memo(move || {
    complicated_computation(captured_variable)
});
```

where use_memo is something like

```
pub fn use_memo<F: Fn() -> T + PartialEq + 'static, T: Clone + 'static>(&mut self, factory: F) -> &T
```

where in the code I can compare factory with a previously stored factory function and decide if factory needs to be rerun.

Obviously this doesn't work, since closures don't implement `PartialEq`, but I wonder if there are ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Every closure has a separate type, even if they're identical, and you can't compare cross-type.

Looking [at a minimal example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5cb0afe96fb03943bb6c1f348f742f79):

```rust
fn main() {
    let b = 2;
    let a = if true {
        || println!("{}", b)
    } else {
        || println!("{}", b)
    };
}
```

we get a compiler error that helpfully explains that **no two closures, even if identical, have the same type**.

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
3 |       let a = if true {
  |  _____________-
4 | |         || println!("{}", b)
  | |         -------------------- expected because of this
5 | |     } else {
6 | |         || println!("{}", b)
  | |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected closure, found a different closure
7 | |     };
  | |_____- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
  |
  = note: expected type `[closure@src/main.rs:4:9: 4:29 b:_]`
          found closure `[closure@src/main.rs:6:9: 6:29 b:_]`
  = note: no two closures, even if identical, have the same type
  = help: consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object

error: aborting due to previous error
```

You could build structs that contain the environment explicitly and compare those rather than using a closure, but I would suggest rethinking your problem and seeing if this is the best way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible: Rust closures are somewhat anonymous type so you can't implement traits on them or anything. And if you used more "explicit" closures where you build up the environment by hand and pass a simple function pointers:

```rust
fn use_memo<T: PartialEq>(&mut self, env: T, func: fn(T))
```

you could compare them:

```rust
fn main(){
    let a: fn(u8) -> u8 = |a: u8| a;
    let b: fn(u8) -> u8 = |a: u8| a % 2;
    println!("{}", a == b) -> false
}
```

but then you'd have the issue that different callbacks would have different environments, therefore the types would not match and you still would not be able to compare them, probably.

Answer (score 0):

I am also quite new in rust, but an idea might be to have a custom trait `FactoryIdentifiable` that defines a method `get_identifier`.

You could then use operator overloading and implement `PartialEq` for this trait and modify your closure's type signature to also require this trait.

```
pub fn use_memo<F: Fn() -> T + FactoryIdentifiable, T: Clone + 'static>(&mut self, factory: F) -> &T
```